# can you solve $x'+x''=\sqrt {x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

And is there a way to solve 
$$ ax''+bx'=f(x)?$$
If there is, how is the method called?

Comment: yes, one of the solutions is $2x\sqrt{x}/3-\sqrt{x}$

Comment: This is a second order linear non-homogeneous differential equation. The idea on how to solve this is to solve the corresponding homogeneous equation $ax''+bx'+cx=0$ and find a function $f$, which satisfy the original equation.

Comment: it's not linear ...@zamarion...

Comment: Let $x'(t)=u(x(t))$; then $x''=x'u'=uu'$, so the differential equation reduces to first order: $u(x)(1+u'(x))=\sqrt{x}$.  Not sure if this can be integrated.

Comment: @user254433  its a function of x on the right side...not a function of the independant variable  t

Comment: @Isham I never claimed otherwise, which is why I wrote $\sqrt{x}$ on the right side, not $\sqrt{t}$

Comment: Thanks. But do you need laplace transform for this kind of solution. And i tought non homogenous would give you a X''(t)+x'(T)=f(t).

Comment: Ah, so it's about seperable vs non seperable differential equation. So some can be solvwe and some cannot. I gave myslef the challenge to solve a simulation of an asteroid entering the solar system. xdotdot=GMx/((x-xs)^2+(y-ys)^2)^1.5 and ydotdot=GMy/((x-xs)^2+(y-ys)^2)^1.5, then solve for xdotdotdot aand xdotdotdotdot. Isolate y= (in the xdotdotdot fonction) Then plug in the y in the xdotdot equation. Then have a fonction of only x. then try to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to reduce such equations (in which the independent variable $t$ does not appear explicitly) to the integration of first order equations.

Let $p=x'$ and consider $p$ as a function of $x$. Then
$$
x''=\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{dp}{dx}\,\frac{dx}{dt}=p\,\frac{dp}{dx}.
$$
The equation becomes
$$
a\,p\,\frac{dp}{dx}+b\,p=f(x),\quad\text{or}\quad\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{f(x)}{a}\,\frac1p-\frac{b}{a}.
$$
Unfortunately this equation does not always have an *easy* solution. If you find $p=p(x)$, you still have to solve
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=p(x),
$$
a first order equation whose solution is
$$
\int\frac{dx}{p(x)}=t+C.
$$
Again, in a lot of cases the integral does not admit a closed form solution in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: This is an Abel equation.  You can look up a table of known solutions: http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0124.pdf